# Detach and Randomize items from separate lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

For each `.container`, I want to `detach()` the `<li>` from their own`<ul>`and append them to each container's `.destination` `<ul>`. The problem is that all `<li>` are being detached from both lists and appended together on both lists.

I want to be able to create a list of all `<li>` that are within each `.container`.

So during test, all of the items with the `.colored` class will detach and append to the `.destination--b` `<ul>`.

```js
$.fn.randomize = function(selector) {
  (selector ? this.find(selector) : this).parent().each(function() {
    $(this)
      .children(selector)
      .sort(function() {
        return Math.random() - 0.5;
      })
      .detach()
      .appendTo(".destination");
  });

  return this;
};
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".container").each(function() {
    $(".item").randomize();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid
}

.destination {
  border: 2px solid
}

ul {
  border: 1px solid blue
}

li {
  border: 1px solid green
}

.colored {
  background: silver
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container container--a">
  <ul class="destination destination--a">
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container container--b">
  <ul class="destination destination--b">
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="item colored">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item colored">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item colored">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="item colored">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item colored">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item colored">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `.destination` is ambiguous, it's appearing in both lists, you need to specify which one exactly. You can do that by searching for a `.destination` from the parent element. Although I noticed that this code will merge `<ul>` lists into one, not sure if that's the desired behavior, you never mentioned?

```js
$.fn.randomize = function(selector) {
  (selector ? this.find(selector) : this).parent().each(function() {
    $(this)
      .children(selector)
      .sort(function() {
        return Math.random() - 0.5;
      })
      .detach()
      .appendTo($(this).parent().find(".destination"));
  });

  return this;
};
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".container").each(function() {
    $(".item").randomize();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid
}

.destination {
  border: 2px solid
}

ul {
  border: 1px solid blue
}

li {
  border: 1px solid green
}

.colored {
  background: silver
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container container--a">
  <ul class="destination destination--a">
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container container--b">
  <ul class="destination destination--b">
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="item colored">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item colored">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item colored">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="item colored">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item colored">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item colored">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```